# How to remove Readonly prop from all above elements on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with input field where readonly is true.

[image]

I also have an edit button, i want to make it so that when the edit button is clicked all the input fields for that row will have readonly false,
but i don't know how to target all all the TD>input within this TR.

Thanks.

The code.

```
<tr>
<td>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
</td>
<td>
    <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="Olympus E-M1 mark II Body" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="Olympus" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="1" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
</td>
<td>
    <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="&euro; 1999,00" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
</td>
<td class="total-price">
    <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="&euro; 1999,00" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="#">
        // The edit button
        <i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: #C7225C; font-size: 20px;"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #C7225C; font-size: 20px;"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Whaat ? all `input` with same `name` ?

Comment: i didn't change that yet, this is only the frontend.

Comment: Use the [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method on the inputs in question

Comment: `$('.fa.fa-edit').on('click', function(){ $(this).parents('tr').first().find('input').prop('readonly', false); });`

Comment: This is is perfect @kosmos, Thank you post this as an answer and i will approve that.

Comment: You are welcome, anyway you've already useful answers, approve any of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.fa-edit').parent().click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').removeAttr('readonly')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="Olympus E-M1 mark II Body" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="Olympus" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="1" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="&euro; 1999,00" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
    </td>
    <td class="total-price">
      <input name="textinput" placeholder="" value="&euro; 1999,00" class="" type="text" style="width: 100%;" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
        // The edit button
        <i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: #C7225C; font-size: 20px;"></i>
    </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #C7225C; font-size: 20px;"></i>
      </a>
    </td>

</table>
```

use [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

> Description: Remove an attribute from each element in the set of matched elements.

NOTE:

1. If dynamically added use event delegation
2. I added the click to anchor tag so i added `.parent()`

Answer (score 2):

Modify you HTML as

```
<a href="#" class="edit">
    // The edit button
    <i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: #C7225C; font-size: 20px;"></i>
</a>
```

Attach the event handler with edit button, then traverse up to `tr` using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). Afterwards [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) can be used to target `:input` to [`removeProp()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).closest('tr').find(':input').removeProp('readonly');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use
`$('input[name=textinput]').removeProp('readonly');`
or try
`$('input[name=textinput]').removeAttr('readonly');`

have look at this https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/fhde3d06/

Comment: How do i target only the Readonly in the above TR, i have multiple rows like this.

Comment: `$('input[name=textinput]')` this will do

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
       tr = $this.closest('tr');

    tr.find('input[type="text"]').attr("readonly", false); 
});
```

You can try to use prop instead of attr.